# Task 'publishApkRelease' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I am able to run gradlew `app:assembleRelease`, but when i run `gradlew app:publishApkRelease`, it gives following error message.

> What went wrong: Task 'publishApkRelease' not found in project ':app'.

I have also tried, `gradlew tasks --all`, it prints a list, but that list does not have publishApkRelease task.

I am wondering if i need to define something extra in my build.gradle my to generate `publishApkRelease` task.

**Gradle file**

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {

            storeFile file(System.getenv("KEY_STORE"))
            storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }

   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

**gradle -version**

---

```
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

    Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
    Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

    Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
    Kotlin:       1.3.11
    Groovy:       2.5.4
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
    JVM:          1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation 25.221-b11)
    OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: Have you created such a task? If not, the task name for the standard maven plugin is `gradlew app:publish` which makes a release build of modules and libraries.

Comment: @Onik : no, can you please tell me how to create a task, i haven;t created any.

Comment: I just checked ways to create tasks, `tasks.register`, but what do i need to define for `app:publishApkRelease` task

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `maven-publish` plugin. In this case `gradlew app:publish` should build a release version of `apk` and publish it. No need to create a custom task for that purpose.